# Feats to take for Paladin Dragon mount?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, paladin, mount

I am running a 12 Paladin/ 8 Barbarian/ 6 Cavalier currently in Pathfinder and the DM allowed me to take a young gold dragon mount.  What feats should I take for it?

Comment: Isn't a CR 11 [young gold dragon](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/dragons/dragon/metallic-gold/young-gold-dragon) a bit, well, *underwhelming* as a mount for your 26th-level character?

Comment: I suppose some Paladin/Cavalier improvements apply, so it does not have to be _that_ bad. Still, it would be good to have the stats of said mount before the feats and some idea about how are you achieving playability in Pathfinder at levels like that. Anyway, it's absolutely much more about the gear than about the feats at these levels.

Comment: I'd ask what you want out of the mount, as that will steer the feats acquired.

Comment: I would also ask about back story. There are some serious alignment issues with your build. "Ex-Paladins

A paladin who ceases to be lawful good, who willfully commits an evil act, or who violates the code of conduct loses all paladin spells and class features (including the service of the paladin's mount, but not weapon, armor, and shield proficiencies). She may not progress any further in levels as a paladin. She regains her abilities and advancement potential if she atones for her violations (see the atonement spell description in Spell Lists), as appropriate."

Comment: @HeyICanChan According to the Draconomicon, that is the lvl 20 standard for a pure paladin (AKA Special mount). So... Considering he's letting a character with only 12 paladin levels take it is actually not that bad

Answer (score 1):

#### Pathfinder Feats

Flyby Attack, Hover, Wingover, Multi-Attack, Shape Breath Weapon, Improved Flight, Combat Expertise, Ability Focus.

Some have pre-reqs.

#### 3.5e Feats

Enlarge/Widen/Extend/Maximize/Empower/Quicken Breath Weapon, Strafing Breath, Flyby Breath, Rapidstrike, Greater Rapidstrike, Adroit Flyby Attack, Leap Attack, Shock Trooper.

Again, some have pre-reqs.

#### Feats For a Bigger Dragon Than Yours

Snatch, Awesome Blow, Swallow Whole.